# Unable to print the value in json objects containing multiple array values in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, printing

```
{
"d" : {
"results" : [
{
 "timeAccount" : "031799ce7bc344a2bb65e7f05cb08c49", "balance" : "10.1388824", "timeAccountType" : "SA_AL_DLY", "userId" : "01000", "accountClosed" : false, "timeUnit" : "DAYS"
}, {
 "timeAccount" : "bc4fb4d44c3e413d8137a59d121c74b6", "balance" : "25.347206", "timeAccountType" : "SA_AL_DLY", "userId" : "01000", "accountClosed" : false, "timeUnit" : "DAYS"
}, {
 "timeAccount" : "f12279ea0d34471581aff90ad71d3f83", "balance" : "5.6249964", "timeAccountType" : "SA_AL_DLY", "userId" : "01000", "accountClosed" : false, "timeUnit" : "DAYS"
}
]
}
}
```

this is my json value i got through api request. I need to print all **balance** present there

```
    data=r.json()

    for results in data['d']:
        print results['results']['balance']
```

i tried to iterate with the above python code but unable to

please help me with this

thanks

```
this is my sample output form 

balance 1 : 10.1388824
balance 2 : 25.347206
balance 3 : 5.6249964
```

Comment: Can you share sample output form?

Comment: Hi @ShadabHussain, i have added the sample output form to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
i = 1
for res in data['d']["results"]:
    print("balance ",i,":", res["balance"])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate this way..

```
for res in data['d']["results"]:
    print (res["balance"])
```

Comment: It Works . Thank you